# How can I save and load a bigmemory::big.matrix object in R?

Tags: r, serialization, r-bigmemory

I'm trying to use big.matrix objects in my R code, but I'm having trouble saving them to a file using `saveRDS`, which is how I normally save objects:

```
> library(bigmemory)
Loading required package: bigmemory.sri
Loading required package: BH

bigmemory >= 4.0 is a major revision since 3.1.2; please see packages
biganalytics and and bigtabulate and http://www.bigmemory.org for more information.

> x <- big.matrix(5, 2, type="integer", init=0,
+ dimnames=list(NULL, c("alpha", "beta")))
> saveRDS(x, "bigmem-test.RDS")
> y <- readRDS("bigmem-test.RDS")
> y
An object of class "big.matrix"
Slot "address":
<pointer: (nil)>

> print(y[])

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x51, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: .Call("GetMatrixAll", x@address)
 2: GetAll.bm(x)
 3: .local(x, ...)
 4: y[]
 5: y[]

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
Selection: 3
```

I assume that saveRDS is somehow failing to realize that the big.matrix object is actually a pointer to some other memory, and is effectively just saving a pointer. Is there any way I can work around this?

(I don't really want to use a file-backed big.matrix object because the object I actually want to save is a complex data structure containing one or more big.matrix objects, so then I would need a backing file for each big.matrix contained in the object, and then the object would be serialized to an indeterminate number of files instead of just one.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But `big.memory` objects sit behind an external pointer so that they *outside the control of R*.  That means that you're idea of saving them as RDS objects *from R* is doomed from the start.

You could cast them to normal objects *eating lots of memory* and then write as RDS.  Otherwise maybe look into `filebased.bigmatrix()` ?

Comment: It would be nice if saveRDS threw an error or something when I tried to save a big.matrix instead of writing a useless RDS file and returning "successfully".

Comment: It can't know.  The external pointer is a perfectly valid R object which you are serializing to file.   It is "merely" your assumption that the pointed-object should be serialized when its very design is made to make it be outside the reach of R.  You simply can't save a bigmemory object this way.

Comment: Ok, I guess that makes sense. I'm not familiar enough with R and bigmemory internals to understand what is and is not "inside" or "outside" or R.

Comment: if `saveRDS` was a generic then `saveRDS.bigmatrix` could throw an error. But it isn't so it can't. But a segfault (in non user code) is a bug, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
> saveRDS(describe(x), "bigmem-test.RDS")
> y <- attach.big.matrix(readRDS("bigmem-test.RDS"))
```

I'm not sure what you intend to achieve though. The above will work within the same R session. But without file-backing, anything you have in memory will be gone after you end the R session and the above will not work because whatever it is pointing to will be gone.